# error in flutter and my phone is not responding never

Tags: flutter

I using google map on my app, and upload the code to my phone, 
the problem is sometimes when I enter and exit to the map quickly, 
the phone is not responding never !!! also I can't turn the phone off!!!

the only solution is re-upload the code again, only this is the solution to make my phone work!!

I try to see the output from the android studio, and I see like that

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Neither user 10737 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK., null)
```

I wish you understand and help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says that the app doesn't have the permission to unlock the phone by itself.

You should add the permission in your code and request it from the user.

If you search it on the net, you will find that Google maps in flutter sometimes needs the permission WAKE_LOCK.

You should add it to your manifest.